Automobile 12V UPS circuit with Li ion battery
Currently I have a battery backup circuit for a GPS device to run on automobile power source and I am trying to improve a few things. Any help is appreciated.

Currently I am facing issues of negative terminal corroding due to arcing in the DPDT switch (solved temporarily by bypassing negative terminal). There is no arcing damage in positive terminal.
The battery backup switch to be replaced with some latching circuit so that once the external power is applied, the backup power is available.
12V output from Li-Ion backup battery is required to connect devices which require 12-30V power source.

There is limitation to keep bigger size modules or more that 2 18650 cells inside the box.


Why switch the ground through the DPDT switch ? I'd just leave it connected. Also may be a good idea throwing in a crowbar on the battery input as automobile connected batteries can have some really odd voltages on them

I planned to totally isolate the battery for transport with DPDT switch. Now I have made negative side direct due to arcing issue. Is there any auto resettable crowbar circuit?
